# How can I disable pop-unders when using Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I know it's possible to disable pop-ups, and that's the default behavior, but It's not affecting the pop-unders.

Comment: Have you tried a general-purpose ad-blocker? I use [AdBlockPlus for chrome](http://adblockplus.org/en/chrome) and can't remember seeing any pop-unders, though I don't browse to sites that might have them very much.

Comment: AdBlockPlus is for you! Internet will "look different", in a pleasant way :)

Comment: Do you have a link to demonstrate this effect? I would like to take a look to see how they circumvent the blocking.

Comment: @J.C. Try http://subtitle.co.il, use the search box to trigger the pop-under

Comment: What is pop-under ?

Answer (score 1):

### Yes,

but you need to block all scripts on a domain using Chrome's own script blocking feature.

---

Why?

Pop-unders are usually via **JavaScript**. In order to disable them, I block javascript on the specific site using <del>the extension **[ScriptNo](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/oiigbmnaadbkfbmpbfijlflahbdbdgdf)**</del>  Chrome's build-in script blocking in:

**Settings →  Show advanced settings → Content settings → JavaScript → JavaScript Exceptions**

At the moment [Chrome's API do not allow proper script blocking](http://forums.informaction.com/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=1676&sid=e460fb4bd6a99b16d5a9772f6d8c3007) which is also why Firefox' [NoScript](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/noscript/) [developer](https://twitter.com/ma1) has not yet ported his extension. Third-party extensions like ScriptNo suffer from the same problem.

The lack of needed API can allow scripts to [still load the first time](http://www.wilderssecurity.com/showpost.php?s=ace401ee676051185495710d184c79ca&p=2068879&postcount=162) you visit a website.

By design there is no option for extensions to effectively block scripts like in Firefox, therefore the only way to stop this behavior is to *block all scripts* on a domain using Chrome's settings which I mentioned at the top.

Comment: It's not working. I think the use a different method for doing it.

Comment: @mokalan You're right, I've radially changed my answer now. Please take another look.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome allows you to set preferences for EACH specific site.

Click on the icon in the browser.

Opens a window allowing to set Java and so on specific to that site.

Now to the pop-unders.

I personally use the Chrommes Poper Blocker extension.

It works for me, but then I have not visited your websites.

Poper Blocker 1.69 
Blocks all these annoying popups and popunders that pop no matter!

If interested, get it here:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/poper-blocker/bkkbcggnhapdmkeljlodobbkopceiche

Answer (score 0):

I have tried lot of different options, addons, scripts, but sorry to disappoint you mate, none of them works perfectly. Some pop-ups do find a way to evade all such methods

Comment: Please name a few sites that evade all methods so that I can check for myself. I'm especially interested in sites that to not use javascript to trigger pop-unders.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a video showing you how to do it.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WBiOlO1jwX4