# How to block pop-up ads

Tags: macos, google-chrome, adblock

On some sites, when I click on a button a pop-up appeared, taking me to another website. The original website is still there, just that a new tab with ad site is opened and that interrupted my workflow. I had both enabled Adblock Plus (no whitelists) and disallowed pop-ups and redirects in the website setting (Google Chrome), but  the pop-ups are not stopped. How can I prevent them?

System: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6
Browser: Google Chrome 72.0.3626.119

Comment: Why do you need those sites surely better to google for the actual publishers sites and download from there

Comment: [how-can-i-disable-pop-unders-when-using-chrome](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/39434/how-can-i-disable-pop-unders-when-using-chrome?rq=1)

Comment: You might also see some of these.. some day [my-ipad-has-a-popup-saying-i-have-a-virus](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/211339/my-ipad-has-a-popup-saying-i-have-a-virus)

Comment: The simplest solution is to press Command+W to close the tab and return to previous tab. I use uBlock Origin as ad-blocker for my browser. Other more complex solution is to learn how to use uMatrix for blocking these annoyances.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to close the pop-up tab and return to previous tab. I use uBlock Origin as ad-blocker for my browser, I would suggest to you to use it too. Other more complex solution is to learn how to use uMatrix for blocking these annoyances.

Answer (score -3):

In Safari you would need to start Safari while holding the Shift key, then empty *all* caches.
This may work in chrome also, try it.

Comment: How would that help for a website designed to show pop ups ?

Comment: While holding the Shift key at startup: this bypasses all caches of Safari. That's how.

Comment: But the website is still the same.. why would a pop-up check whether cache exists or not, before launching?

Comment: Try it. Stop Safari, then start while holding the shift key.

Comment: Can you please provide some documentation, from Apple or any other reputable site, backing this up?  I have a hard time understanding how this will work as you've described.

Comment: Look in Apple forums, almost every week there is the same issue discussed and the same method given.